# Firebase group by with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an application, using AngularJS and Firebase. In a part of it's Firebase Database, I have to store pictures, grouped by events, then those events are grouped by region.

So to get them all grouped by region it's simpler, but getting them grouped by events then by region is quite difficult.
So anyone has a solution for it?

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not get to see the problem here. 
How are you structuring your database?

From what I've read it seems you are already grouping the pictures by events.

Comment: @Lirianer Thanks for you answer, Yes I'm grouping them in my database, but I'm talking about getting them in arrays of arrays

Comment: Why not just have your image data have two extra elements: `region` and `event`, then retrieve the corresponding `image`s that have the specific `region` and `event` that you need?